# JavaScript function returning value undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating Google Chrome Extension, and declared a function in background.js that is hitting a API and should return a value but it is returning undefined value. Writing console log before return statement has value.

```
var produImage;

function getImage() {
    fetch('/api/images.json').then(
        function (response) {
            response.json().then(function (data) {
                var dataresponse=data.results;
                for (var obj = 0; obj < dataresponse.length; obj++)
                {
                  produImage=dataresponse[0].url_170x135;
                  //console.log writing value
                  console.log(produImage);
                  //returning undefind
                  return produImage;
                }
            });

        }
    );
}

//call to function
 '<td><img width="50" height="50" src="' + getImage() + '"/></td>'
```

> ### Issue
>
> console.log(produImage)
>
> > *giving value*
>
> return produImage
>
> > *returning undefind*

## **Edited**

Also tried as suggested by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7159043/chris)

```
function getImage() {
    return fetch('/api/images.json').then(
        function (response) {
            return response.json().then(
                function (data) {
                    ;
                    return data.results[0].url_170x135;
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

and then call to function

```
 getImage().then(function (imageSrc) {
      const html = `<td><img width="50" height="50" src="${imageSrc}"/></td>`;
});
```

but still I can't concatenate value to `var result` getting `undefined`

I want to concatenate like this:

```
result = `<tr>
<td>${How To concatenate Here}</td>
<td>${dResponse[obj].category_path}</td>
<td>${dResponse[obj].price}</td>
</tr>`;
```

> Please suggest me, how can I get plain result from getImage() that is returning promise object?

Comment: See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: Declare var  produImage in main function ,  add return statement out of promise 'then' chain scope and add
to main function body

Comment: first asynchronous, second, makes no sense to return in a loop....unless you really want to exit on the first iteration.

Comment: @epascarello yeah really, loop makes no sense. I will clean it.

Answer (score 1):

You're only returning from the innermost function, not from `getImage`.

To make this clearer, I would rewrite as follows (hope this is correct, typing from a phone):

```
async function getImage() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/images.json');

  const data = await response.json();

  return Promise.resolve(data.results[0].url_170x135);
}
```

Notes:

- You should add error handling to this
- The loop you had there was probably legit in the original code, but served no value in what you posted imho

If you cannot use async / await, the following should work:

```
function getImage() {
  return fetch('/api/images.json').then(
    function (response {
      return response.json().then(
        function (data) {;
          return data.results[0].url_170x135;
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

### Edit

When you resolve the result of the function, use (in an async function)

```
const html = await `<td><img width="50" height="50" src="${getImage()}"/></td>`;
```

or (in a non-async function)

```
getImage().then(function(imageSrc) {
  const html = `<td><img width="50" height="50" src="${imageSrc}"/></td>`;
  // do something with 'html'
});
```

P.S. I think the code would benefit from using lambdas in general. In my above example, this would be nicer:

```
getImage().then((imageSrc) => {
  const html = `<td><img width="50" height="50" src="${imageSrc}"/></td>`;
  // do something with 'html'
});
```

Comment: You didn't address the second mistake: getImage() call inside the string concatenation.

Comment: Fair enough, focused on the title ;-)

Comment: @Chris I'm calling it from image tag `src="+ getImage() +" ` 
after implement above now getting **[object Promise]** it should be plain url instead

Comment: @Kuldeep Edited my answer to show how to deal with that.

Comment: @Chris I have result variable where I am concatenating string. Using

````js
getImage().then((imageSrc) => {
  const html = `<td><img width="50" height="50" src="${imageSrc}"/></td>`;
  result += html;
});

````
also getting undefined. Any suggestion please?

Comment: @Kuldeep can you please edit your question to reflect your changed code (don't change what you had, but add to it to make sure others can follow the conversation)?

Comment: Ok, so I believe the issue is that you're trying to concatenate outside the function passed to `then`. What are you doing with `result` afterwards? If you're inserting that into the DOM, you can just do that within the function passed to `getImage(...).then` and everything should be fine.

Comment: Please note that you can't do anything synchronous in asynchronous code. So if you try to use a result assigned to a variable within asynchronous code from right after you call that code, it won't be available yet!

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for help me. Actually, I am creating html in `result` variable from API data and need to call another API with parameter imageId that is a property of previous API result. So that is way I can't fill result variable within `getImage().then({ })`
Please suggest if it is possible.

Comment: @KuldeepGill, can you not call this next API from within the function passed to `then`?

Comment: @KuldeepGill if this helped you, would you mind accepting (or at least upvoting) the answer?

Comment: Hi @Chris, still same issue, please advise.
Thank you!

Comment: @KuldeepGill see my previous commemt, can you not call this next API from within the function passed to `then`? If not, why not?